# trying to save a HashMap<Item, Integer> in h2 database failed because of "Value too long ... BINARY(255)"

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am using Spring Boot with h2 db and JPA Repository.

I am adding an Item entity to a `HashMap<Item, Integer>`, Integer for quantity, and it works (seen it in debugger), but when it runs:

```
orderRepository.save(orderMapper.toEntity(orderDto));
```

it fails to add the HashMap to the database. I want an order entry with a list of items from which I will iterate using angular and display them to the user.

This is the **error** I am getting:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Value too long for column """ITEMS_LIST"" BINARY(255)": "X'aced0005737200116a6176612e7574696c2e486173684d61700507dac1c31660d103000246000a6c6f6164466163746f724900097468726573686f6c647870... (384)"; SQL statement:

insert into orders (created_date, items_list, total_cost, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [22001-199]
```

This is the **Order entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id_order;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "total_cost")
    private double totalCost;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "items_list")
    private HashMap<Item, Integer> item = new HashMap<>();
```

**Item Entity** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;
```

**User Entity**:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Orders order;
```

I think the problem is that you cannot store HashMap objects in db, but if it is possible could you tell me how or else how can I store a (key, value) list in the database?

Or maybe instead of storing the whole Item entity to the db, should I only store the item Id and quantity?

Comment: you could create another enitity `OrderItem` with the foreign key `id_order` and another field `item`. Each instance will represent a single `item` related to an order. So for n items in an order, you'll have n instances of `OrderItem`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm pretty bad at database relationships and db annotations. I have a `total_cost` column in `Orders` entity in which I want to multiply the `itemPrice` with `quantity` for all the items in the order. If I don't find a way to somehow store a `key,value Map` I will definitely do it as you say.

Comment: Can you share the schema of the table in the H2 database that you are using?

Comment: @vatsalgosar I added every entity that I have to the original post. My web app is so that a user can have maximum one order at a time.